# Formatting list of queries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings

I have a file of `SQL` (actually `HiveQL`) queries terminated by semicolon (`;`). I need to obtain a list of formatted queries from this file. Formatting includes replacing multiple spaces with single one and removing extra spaces in cases like `'( ', ' )', ' ,'`. So, the following is my approach and it looks monstrous:

```
fdHql = open(args.hql, 'r')
hql_file = fdHql.read()
fdHql.close()
queries = [re.sub('\s+', ' ', each.replace('\n', ' ').strip()).replace('( ', '(').replace(' )', ')').replace(' ,', ',') for each in hql_file.split(';')]
```

Is there a better way to implement same behavior?

Answer (score 3):

You can eliminate the `.close()` using a `with ... as ...:` statement.

Since newlines are white-space characters, `re.sub('\s+', ' ', ...)` will already convert any `'\n'` characters to a space, so the `.replace('\n', ' ')` is unnecessary.

And you don't need to write everything on one line, even when you
want a "one-liner".

```
with open(args.hql, 'r') as fdHql:
    queries = [
               re.sub('\s+', ' ', each.strip())
                   .replace('( ', '(')
                   .replace(' )', ')')
                   .replace(' ,', ',')
               for each in fdHql.read().split(';')
              ]
```

Of course, the clearest is to move the work to a helper function.

```
def _format_sql(sql):
    return re.sub('\s+', ' ', sql.strip())      \
               .replace('( ', '(')              \
               .replace(' )', ')')              \
               .replace(' ,', ',')

with open(args.hql, 'r') as fdHql:
    queries = [ _format_sql(each) for each in fdHql.read().split(';') ]
```